# Parse into Conditional Jinja Template from Pre-defined CSV file

Tags: python, csv, conditional-statements, jinja2

Parse into Conditional Jinja Template from Pre-defined CSV file:

**CSV File:**

```
vlan_id, network, mask, gateway, routed, description, gateway_name
2, 10.10.10.0, 255.255.255.0, 10.10.10.1, yes, internal network, localL3_switch
3, 192.168.0.0, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.0.1, yes, DMN Network, local_ASA_Fw
4, 192.168.1.0, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.1.1, yes, Big-IP Int Network, local_ASA_Fw
5, 10.10.11.0, 255.255.255.0, 10.10.11.1, yes, internal network2, localL3_switch
6, 10.10.11.0, 255.255.255.0, 10.10.11.1, yes, internal network2, localL3_switch
3, 100.100.100.0, 255.255.255.0, 100.100.100.1, yes, Internet, local_ASA_Fw
```

localL3_switch_jinja2.j2 template file has following content this template should run only if conditions match with gateway_name only.

interface vlan {{vlan_id}}
 ip address {{gateway}} {{mask}}
 no shutdown
!

Comment: I want to control rendering based in Jinja template only. If condition match then only execute the rendering for that row, else, look for next till end of row and print all output in text file,

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense. Your template is being rendered by some kind of Python function anyway, so you might as well do the logic there.

Comment: is it not possible?